# Build from github on Heroku is stuck, no lines are being written

Tags: python, heroku

I made changes to my program and now, when I press to deploy, the app gets stuck. It says build is in progress although after 20 min not a single line has been written in the log. I tried deleting my app and creating a new one, with the same repository from github, and it still gets stuck. Anyone can help pls?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically, I let the build run for a bit more before deleting the app, and it got a timeout error. Then I deployed it again and it worked.